# How do I fix the hide/show script of object?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a script to hide the object after 2 seconds and then show it after 2 seconds too but it just hide and not show again:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class HideObject : MonoBehaviour
{
    private float disappearTime = 2f;
    private float appearTime = 2f;

    private float disappearTimer = 0f;
    private float appearTimer = 0f;

    private bool isBlockVisible = true;

    void Update()
    {
        if (isBlockVisible)
        {
            disappearTimer += Time.deltaTime;
            if (disappearTimer >= disappearTime)
            {
                gameObject.SetActive(false);
                isBlockVisible = false;
                disappearTimer = 0f;
                Debug.Log("hide");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            appearTimer += Time.deltaTime;
            if (appearTimer >= appearTime)
            {
                gameObject.SetActive(true);
                isBlockVisible = true;
                appearTimer = 0f;
                Debug.Log("show");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I use Debug.Log to check but the console only appear: hide

I test with the empty object

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are disabling your gameObject to make it disappear (using `gameObject.SetActive(false);`) , this also stops all the scripts attached to it. Your code will not bo able to run the Update() function anymore while disabled and it will never appear. You need to run this code from another object or not disable the whole gameObject

Answer (score 0):

Show wont work on this situation because **Update** method wont work on *gameobject.Setactive = false*

Instead you can use

```
myGameObject.GetComponent<Renderer>().enabled = false
```

This will disable renderer component.

Renderer should be renamed with either *MeshRenderer* or *SpriteRenderer* etc.